What type of model/analysis to use to predict events in time series data
I have a bunch of time series with known real-world events (one event per t/s). An event is not necessarily visible as a change in the t/s, but is know to have occurred in the real world.
I wonder if I can train a model to learn if there are any characteristic patterns preceding the events to use in predicting similar events in other t/s or in the same t/s in the future.
This isn't intervention analysis, since we're not concerned with what happened after the event. Also isn't changepoint analysis, since we know exactly when the events occurred. And also isn't anomaly detection, since the events need not necessarily have had an impact on the data.
Is RNN the right or best tool for this task? Is there a general name for this type of analysis?
To illustrate, here's a dummy t/s with an event marked by a dashed line. I have a bunch of other t/ss that are similar, each t/s is kind-of a unit of replication. In this dummy t/s, the event is preceded by a kind of a 'pulse', with value going sharply up then sharply down. This is just to illustrate that there might be something characteristic in the t/s preceding the event that could serve as a predictor, not necessarily a pulse like this.

Then I have other time series where an event has not occurred (that by far outnumber those where an event has occurred). The aim is to train a model to predict whether and when events might occur in a future t/s, like in an early-warning system (in this dummy future t/s showing a similar 'pulse' for the illustration purpose only - a model could predict an event at time step 17, just after the pulse).


When I see "event" I think "survival analysis." RNNs are outside my expertise, but you might get some ideas from: Wiegrebe, S., Kopper, P., Sonabend, R. et al. Deep learning for survival analysis: a review. Artif Intell Rev 57, 65 (2024), an open-access article.

@EdM unfortunately, survival analysis deals with "time-to-event" data, which is different.

What makes survival analysis so fundamentally different from your situation? A simple Cox model clearly won't work here, but more complex models (e.g., cure models to distinguish whether an event is likely to happen, joint models of longitudinal variables along with event times to estimate when the event happens as a function of longitudinal-variable values) seem to be on point. With your type of data it's just not clear to a human what patterns in the longitudinal data are associated with whether and when the event might happen. I suspect that deep learning might help find them.
